# Overly Broad? "Dealing with aggressive animals in a professional environment"

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Is the question [Dealing with aggressive animals in a professional environment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11080) overly broad? It is not clear if the question is about adoptable pets, visiting pets, or recently  surrender pets (i.e. shelter).  Or maybe it is someone just curious about working at one of these facilities and is not aware of training that is required for the job.

Should the question be closed as overly broad?

Comment: Giving any general advice other than a full course of dog psychology or not handling them at all will be irresponsible and potentially dangerous to uninformed readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like they're asking about how to handle aggressive dogs. Which is something that's useful to know, especially if you work in an animal shelter, veterinary office, or boarding house.

But like one comment said, handling aggressive dogs is different than how you would handle other animals, and the answer wouldn't apply to reptiles, birds, rodents, or even cats really.

I think it should be edited to be made specifically about dogs. That way if someone comes in later to ask how to handle an aggressive snake, their question doesn't get closed because we already have this one that doesn't (and probably never will) answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so and the context isn't really relevant, it's just more likely to be encountered in certain settings. Nevertheless, dealing with aggressive dogs, in particular, is something many of us may need to do and advice with respect to that is probably a good thing.

Comment: The context is very important. I sometimes just refuse to work with some aggressive dogs while I will muzzle or tranquilize others. The general advice will also differ from example country to country, breed of dog, type of aggression etc.